# Opening a Latex Overleaf template: Parskip.sty not found?

Tags: latex

I would like to open [this](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/rishi-shahs-resume/vgxvkmxktyxn) cv template on my tex. However, after downloading it, I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `parskip.sty' not found.
```

I believe I downloaded the source files correctly and moved them into Latex packages, including the cls. I also tried updating the packages on my Latex.

Can anyone please assist? Thank you.

Comment: Please 1) make a [mre] that will allow us to reproduce the problem, 2) include your .log file and 3) state which tex distribution you have

Answer (score -1):

You need to download the missing file which is the `parskip-2001-04-09.sty` from [source](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/parskip?lang=en) and save it as `parskip.sty` to where your other files are.

Tested on Ubuntu.

Comment: The current parskip version is `2021-03-14 v2.0h` - please don't suggest to use a 20 year old version that's just available for compatibility reasons

Comment: The version/date is 2021-03-14 but the file name is `parskip-2001-04-09.sty`. Please can you check by yourself before concluding it's an old version. Not sure this is a fair comment.

Comment: The file you link to is version `\ProvidesPackage{parskip}[2001/04/09 non-zero parskip adjustments]` That's the old version keep around for compatibility reasons. If you want the current version, you would need to extract it from the dtx file or simply let your tex distribution install it.

Comment: The file `parskip-2001-04-09.sty` is only meant to be used if the user explicitly calls the parskip package with the compatibility option `\usepackage{parskip}[=v1]` However this won't adjust the spacing around headings.

Comment: OK. Thanks. It sounds you know what you are talking about. Perhaps you could provide a better working answer for the OP and myself? Where is the dtx file? How to let the tex distribution install it? At least I downloaded the OP's template and tested my solution which does work in terms of overcoming the latex error and produce the correct spacing around headings (despite you said it wouldn't.)

Comment: No I can't provide an answer. The solution to the problem is to install the missing package, but how this is done depends on the tex distribution and the OP never answered to my inquiry.

Comment: and as for where to find the dtx file: it is in the same folder on ctan you linkted to in your question. Download the complete folder and the run `pdflatex parskip.ins` to extract the current `.sty` file. (but installing it via your tex distribution is much better as this will allow you to keep up-to-date with further changes)

Comment: You can see the incorrect spacing here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3V0A.png

Comment: Thanks for the further explanations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232213/discussion-between-l001d-and-samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz).